# Facebook like button exploit

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I was disappointed to see my name as a facebook like on a kind of sexual site.The thing is the sexual website owner has put another popular facebook page's like button under his sexual post.Isn't this a like exploit? What can someone do about this ?

Comment: Report it as an abuse.